# Is it possible to add the Ubuntu Software Center to sources.list?

Tags: apt, software-center

I would like to install some of the things on the Ubuntu Software Center via command line (apt-get).  Is this possible?  If so does anyone have the url handy to add to sources.list? I can't seem to find this documented anywhere.  Looking for something like:

```
deb http://apps.ubuntu.com/ precise main
```

> edit <

Finding the package name worked great for most free apps.

Is there a difference if it's a commercial application (even though it's free)?  I'm specifically interested in:

http://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/perforce-version-management

The version info contains: perforce-version-management 2012.3+1-0ubuntu1 However, 'apt-cache search perforce' or 'apt-cache search perforce-version-management' don't turn up this app.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to find out which name the application you want to install has. There is no PPA.

When you click on an application in the USC, you just can scroll down and see the package name.
[image]

(look under version)

Comment: Yes the sources list is the same Software center is a GUI for aptitude.